# Python cv2 read two image path in one request

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, yolo, darknet

Hi Stackoverflow community, is there a way to give two image for cv2 in one time?
i'm using python 2.7 below is the code i try:

```
image1 = abc.jpg
image2 = def.jpg
imageArry = []
imageArry.append(image1,image2)
cv2.imread(imageArry)
```

this won't work because is not correct, my question is if success to append two image in one array, in cv2.imread will it get two picture in one time?

Comment: No, `cv2.imread()` reads only one image at a time, BTW why do you wanna do that ?

Comment: @ZdaR i have two request in one time and the request will have two image at one time

Comment: Write a custom function which accepts a list and reads the images

Comment: @planetmaker i doing it right now see it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution it might able to do this in below:

```
image1 = abc.jpg
image2 = def.jpg
imageArry = []
for ix in [image1, image2]
   imageArry.append(ix)
   imageCatch = ','.join(imageArry)
getCatch1,getCatch2 = imageCatch.split(',')
if getCatch1 is not None:
   img = cv2.imread(getCatch1)
elif getCatch2 is not None:
    img =cv2.imread(getCatch2)
```

it might not looks good but it currently not error for this, if anyone can make it better can try thank you.